# jQuery .text() will not update

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My issue is that when there is a "keydown" event triggered, the textarea's text will not update with what is currently in the textarea, just what was originally in the textarea. Check out the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qSbLp/1/) that helps me describe the issue. Click on the word test and try to edit the textarea that appears. Notice that the alerts still only result in "Test", not what it has been changed to.

```
<script>
$('#content').click(function () {
    var content = $('#content').text();
    $('#content').html("<textarea id='text'>" + content + "</textarea>");
    $('textarea').width($(window).width()).height($(window).height());
    $("#content").unbind('click');
});

$("body").delegate("textarea", "keydown",function(e){
    myAjaxFunction($('textarea').text());
    alert($('textarea').text());
});

function myAjaxFunction(value) {
$.post("update.php?filename=" + filename, { content: value });
}
</script>
```

Comment: How many `<textarea>` elements do you have on your page? Try `myAjaxFunction($('#text').text());`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some changes:

1) You need to use `on()` instead of `delegate()` because as of jQuery 1.7, `.delegate()` has been superseded by the `.on()` method

2) Use `keyup` instead of `keydown` event.

3) Use **[val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)** to get the value of your textarea

```
$("body").on("keyup", "textarea",function(e){
    alert($('textarea').val());
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qSbLp/3/)**

Comment: Beauty. I did what you said before you updated the post and it worked wonderfully. Thank you very much!

Comment: @user2416047 Probably should set it as the Accepted Answer then :)

Answer (score 0):

According to [jquery text help](http://api.jquery.com/text/), it said:

> The .text() method cannot be used on form inputs or scripts. To set or
>   get the text value of input or textarea elements, use the .val()
>   method. To get the value of a script element, use the .html() method.

So just replace text() to be val(), check http://jsfiddle.net/qSbLp/4/

```
$('#content').click(function () {
    var content = $('#content').text();
    $('#content').html("<textarea id='text'>" + content + "</textarea>");
    $('textarea').width($(window).width()).height($(window).height());
    $("#content").unbind('click');
});

$("body").delegate("textarea", "keydown",function(e){
    alert($('textarea').val());
});

function myAjaxFunction(value) {
$.post("update.php?filename=" + filename, { content: value });
}
```